# Change table row labels in R

Tags: r, datatable

I created a table using `library ("data.table")` :

```
library ("data.table") 

Table

    Head1      Head2      Head3     Head4
1: Value1.1   Value1.2  Value1.3  Value1.4
2: Value2.1   Value2.2  Value2.3  Value2.4
3: Value3.1   Value3.2  Value3.3  Value3.4
4: Value4.1   Value4.2  Value4.3  Value4.4
5: Value5.1   Value5.2  Value5.3  Value5.4
```

I tried changing the numbers on the left

```
1:
2:
3:
4:
5:
```

using `rownames(Tables)`:

```
rownames(Table)=c("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name6")
```

but the result is invariant. The row numbers don't change to the names I am trying to change using `rownames()`. What I want to do is:

```
        Head1      Head2      Head3     Head4
Name1: Value1.1   Value1.2  Value1.3  Value1.4
Name2: Value2.1   Value2.2  Value2.3  Value2.4
Name3: Value3.1   Value3.2  Value3.3  Value3.4
Name4: Value4.1   Value4.2  Value4.3  Value4.4
Name5: Value5.1   Value5.2  Value5.3  Value5.4
```

Comment: Post the code you are using to create the initial table.

Comment: I created this example because I can't display the code completely. I used `rbindlist` to go from a list to the table I put in. Do you need something specific?

Comment: `data.table` does not support row names. Instead, you may add new column for row names.

Comment: If you convert the data.table to a data.frame with `setDF(Table)`, you will be able to set the row names for printing purposes. If you want to preserve the original data.table, use `copy()` to make a copy first.

Comment: Thank you so much guys.